# What is preventing this simple HTML code from working?

Tags: javascript, html

A very simple attempt in which I'd just want to manage to use HTML and JS together, but going through the code a dozen times I cannot locate the issue.
(Upon clicking the box I want it to change color).

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

   <div id="block" onclick="myFunction()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: blue"></div>

   <script>
   var myFunction = function() {
   document.getElementById("block").style.background-color = "green";
   </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Missing `}` of `myFunction`. `background-color` ==> `backgroundColor`. To see the color changing you need some innerHTML in `div`

Comment: @JaagupAverin: please describe a bit more the expected behavior. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `background-color` is an invalid property name literal
2. You've left the `}` off the end of the function expression

The second is easily fixed (just add the `}` at the end, and also a `;` because it's an expression).

Re the first: If you open your browser's web console (always best to have it open when developing), you'll see an error pointing to

```
document.getElementById("block").style.background-color = "green";
// Here ------------------------------------------^
```

JavaScript property name literals can't have `-` in them. To handle that, browsers use camelCased property names for CSS names with dashes, in this case `backgroundColor`:

```
document.getElementById("block").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var myFunction = function() {
   document.getElementById("block").style.backgroundColor = "green";
};
```

```html
<div id="block" onclick="myFunction()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: blue"></div>
```

You can also use brackets notation and a string:

```
document.getElementById("block").style["background-color"] = "green";
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var myFunction = function() {
   document.getElementById("block").style["background-color"] = "green";
};
```

```html
<div id="block" onclick="myFunction()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`background-color` should be `backgroundColor`, no variable in JavaScript can have `-`. And, you have an syntax error; `}` to declare the end of function.

```js
var myFunction = function() {
   document.getElementById("block").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
   <div id="block" onclick="myFunction()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: blue"></div>
```